# Load function at runtime in C++

Tags: c++, loadlibrary, dynamic-binding

I have following problem:

My program should decide at runtime to load an function (in this case GetExtendedTcpTable()) or not, because the method is not available in Windows 2000!? (can't start the software only in Windows 2000)

Thank you for your help!

greets leon22

Comment: and why you want it to load at runtime and not in normal way?

Comment: @fazo: Because it is not available on some OS versions, as the OP said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't quite specify your question, but I suppose that you want to load the function dynamically based on the OS version.

To determine the OS version, you can use `GetVersionEx`. To load a function dynamically, first use `LoadLibrary` to retrieve the module handle of its DLL, and then use `GetProcAddress` to retrieve a function pointer to the function. You will need to cast that function pointer to the correct prototype.

Comment: I would omit the GetVersionEx check.  Just use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.  If the function is there, use it (if it's not there, don't use it :-)).  If you use GetVersionEx you run into problems if a service pack decides to add the function afterwards.

Comment: @Patrick: Yeah, this is probably a good idea. There are some cases, however, when you want to make sure the OS version is one that you expect, or at least newer than some version that is known to you.

Comment: Ok, I go this way but when I load the lib explicit I get an buffer overrun in VS2008!? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing what you did. I suggest that you start a new question.

Comment: I'm also tried Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs in VS2008 but I get a linker warning: LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:iphlpapi.dll ignored; no imports found from iphlpapi.dll, but I need a function from iphlpapi and get after this warning an linker error -> weird! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

If the function is not available on a particular platform, you want to determine at compile time whether or not to load it not at runtime.  During the configury of the build, you determine if the function is available and compile appropriately.

Comment: Well I totaly disagree. It's a good thing to make your software work properly on some OS, but without some functions. It's much cleaner for user, than: "If you have windows xp download this, if 2000 download that..." etc.

Comment: @Kamil  I cannot, as I am not familiar with Windows.  However, if the platform fails to provide adequate tools to do a job properly, that does not change the proper solution to the problem.  It just indicates that the platform cannot do the job properly.

Comment: Solution for taking out pointers to functions, to keep compatibility with previous versions of Windows is quite common. And like I said, it's case when other functions of software works well, and only one is not available let's say on Windows XP. It doesn't make sense to drop compatibility with this version of OS, or make special package for it, if the only difference is this one little function. Also another way would be making it as plugin, but often it's not worth to make pluginapi for your own app just for one function

Comment: @Kamil  The inability of a platform to implement the correct solution (which is compile-time determination) does not change the correctness of the solution.  The work-around is a hack.  Run-time evaluation of the capability of the platform is bloat.

Comment: It does at compile time, but then on older platform, at runtime it won't resolve depndency and fail to start. Also your last comment proves, that you even don't know what is purpose of such solution